# Cannot select elements with jquery after a html() load in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox works fine

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code that runs in a `display:none;` classed: `divtab1`

```
function ToggleTab(tab_id)
{
 $('.divtab1').html('<div class="promo2">Testing</div>...more');
 $('.promo2').css("border", "1px solid gray");
}
```

html document:

```
<a href="javascript:ToggleTab(1);">try</a>

<div class="divtab"></div>
```

It works fine in Mozilla but not in IE. The actual data come from an ajax request but nothing can be selected in IE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the jQuery a bit wrong, Instead of writing global functions and using javascript: in the href attribute, you should add an event handler to the a tag in question, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.someclass').click(function(){
        $('.divtab').html(...);
        $('.promo2').css("border", "1px solid gray");
    });
});
```

Then just put a `class="someclass"` on your `<a>` tag (or any tag) and you wont need to add javascript stuff in your href, in fact I would recommend against using an `<a>` as it is not even a link.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `<div class="divtab1"></div>` in HTML.

Fix it to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_div">try</a>

<div class="divtab1"></div>
```

And try again

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle_div').click(function() {
        $('.divtab1').html('<div class="promo2">Testing</div>...more');
        $('.promo2').css("border", "1px solid gray");
    });   
});
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/PhMmC/5/